How to limit number of foreign key references?
There are two tables: clients and contacts, in contacts there is a foreign key many contacts to one client. How can I set the maximum number of rows referencing one client? For example, no more than 3 contacts for 1 client.

That's a business rule, not a database integrity rule. Do it in the code. Off topic.

So you want to limit COUNT(*) GROUP BY client_id to 3; the fact the field is a foreign key to another table has nothing to do with it... I suppose you could add a number field, make client_id, number not null unique and have a constraint like number BETWEEN 1 and 3 but it does not look like something I, for one, would want to have in my database.

Create an extra column in your contacts table, put a check constraint on this column with the maximum number of contacts and update this field when you create or delete a relation. The update will lock the record, so it even works with concurrent operations

@user207421 This is a domain rule rather than a business one. The OP is right to do it in the database.

You can do something like this:
INSERT INTO contact_ws_client (contact_id, client_id)
SELECT 'contact_id', 'client_id'
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM contact_ws_client WHERE client_id = 'client_id'
) < 3


That won't work if there are two concurrent inserts - they cannot see each other's results.
